# Consulta LIKE não funciona quando uso setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho este filtro de consulta que não retorna nenhum resultado quando adiciono `setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)` e quando comento essa linha os resultados aparecem como esperado. Como posso contornar esse problema?

```
$connPdo = new \PDO(DBDRIVE . ': host=' . DBHOST . '; dbname=' . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $connPdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);//Quando removo esta linha funciona

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . self::$table . ' o LEFT JOIN equipamentos e ON o.equipamento = e.idEquipamento 
         LEFT JOIN users u ON o.cliente = u.idUser WHERE o.empresa = :id AND e.name LIKE :keys
         OR u.name LIKE :keys OR u.phone LIKE :keys';
    $stmt = $connPdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',  $data['empresa']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':keys', "%" . $data['key'] . "%");
    $connPdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Nenhum ordem encontrada!");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente em casos iniciais de dev, seria legal utilizar `ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Aqui nesse link [Stack OverFlow PDO MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not) (em inglês, a resposta está bem explicada, inclusive no final do item **2** e início do item **3** ele descreve mais ou menos assim:

> Em outras palavras, o mesmo código PDO será igualmente vulnerável (ou não vulnerável) a ataques de injeção, independentemente de sua EMULATE_PREPARESconfiguração. A única diferença é onde ocorre a substituição do parâmetro - com EMULATE_PREPARES, ocorre na biblioteca PDO; sem EMULATE_PREPARES, ocorre no servidor MySQL.
>
> Sem EMULATE_PREPARESvocê pode obter erros de sintaxe em tempo de
> preparação em vez de em tempo de execução; com EMULATE_PREPARESvocê só
> obterá erros de sintaxe em tempo de execução porque o PDO não tem uma
> consulta para dar ao MySQL até o tempo de execução. Observe que isso
> afeta o código que você escreverá ! Especialmente se você estiver
> usando PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION!
>
> É necessário sempre ter o MySQL client e server instalado, e verificar se na versão instalada os drivers suportados estão instalados para preparar

======================================================================

> Estou surpreso que ninguém tenha mencionado uma das maiores razões para desativar a emulação. Com a emulação ativada, o PDO retorna todos os números inteiros e flutuantes como strings . Quando você desativa a emulação, inteiros e floats no MySQL se tornam inteiros e floats no PHP.

======================================================================

> Cuidado ao desabilitar PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES(ativar preparações nativas) quando seu PHP pdo_mysqlnão é compilado em arquivos mysqlnd.
>
> Como old libmysqlnão é totalmente compatível com algumas funções, pode
> levar a bugs estranhos, por exemplo:
>
> Perda de bits mais significativos para inteiros de 64 bits ao vincular
> como PDO::PARAM_INT(0x12345678AB será cortado para 0x345678AB na
> máquina de 64 bits) Incapacidade de fazer consultas simples como LOCK
> TABLES(ele lança SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is
> not supported in the prepared statement protocol yetexceção) Precisa
> buscar todas as linhas do resultado ou fechar o cursor antes da
> próxima consulta (com mysqlndou emulado o prepara automaticamente faz
> isso funcionar para você e não fica fora de sincronia com o servidor
> mysql) Esses bugs eu descobri no meu projeto simples quando migrei
> para outro servidor que usava libmysqlpara o pdo_mysqlmódulo. Talvez
> haja muito mais bugs, não sei. Também testei no novo debian jessie de
> 64 bits, todos os bugs listados ocorrem quando eu apt-get install
> php5-mysql, e desaparecem quando eu apt-get install php5-mysqlnd.
>
> Quando PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARESé definido como verdadeiro (como
> padrão) - esses bugs não acontecem de qualquer maneira, porque o PDO
> não usa instruções preparadas neste modo. Portanto, se você usar
> pdo_mysqlcom base em libmysql("mysqlnd" substring não aparece no campo
> "Versão da API do cliente" da pdo_mysqlseção em phpinfo) - você não
> deve PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARESdesligar.

======================================================

> Caso desabilite seria interessante acionar disparos de erros do php e PDO, usando try catch, e habilitando depuração de erros Database

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).